# How to disable keyboard input in curses

Tags: python-3.x, curses

I have some long running tasks and would like to disable the keyboard input during the procedure. After the keyboard is disabled, the keyboard inputs will be discarded automatically.

```
disable keyboard
running the task
enable keyboard
```

Can I do this with python curses?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's no input until you ask for it, so there's no need to explicitly disable it. But, to flush the input queue before you start taking input again, just call `curses.flushinp()`.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not quite true: it's true that input won't be assigned to a variable unless there is a request but if you do call the function (at least with `getnstr()`) input will be in the buffer/queue so that the characters already typed would be detected first. Note that they point out that whilst the keyboard is disabled any input would be discarded. Admittedly this is with C but I guess that Python bindings would be the same.

Comment: As I said -- call `flushinp()` before you start again. How is that "not quite true"?

Comment: You're right that it will get rid of the input. What I meant was that there can be input before you ask for it. Flushing it will get rid of it but it was still there.